# How to mock an InboundAdapter in spring-integration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

When I have the following simple IntegrationFlow written with Spring Boot and Spring Integration:

```java
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow itf() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(Tcp.netServer(1111)).id("Inbound"))
                .transform(p -> p) //more complex transform and filter chain
                .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(Tcp.netClient("localhost", 2222)), a -> a.id("Outbound")).get();
    }
```

I can write a UnitTest and try to mock the Inbound and OutboundAdapter with following code:

```java
@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = {"Inbound", "Outbound"})
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MockIntegrationContext mockIntegrationContext;

    @Test
    public void testIntegrationFlow() {
        mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageSourceFor("Inbound", (MessageSource<String>) () -> MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello").build());
        mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor("Outbound", p -> System.out.println("Hallo"));
    }
}
```

This will throw an Exception because the inboundAdapter is not of type `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`.

Is there any way to replace the `Tcp.inboundAdapter` with a Mock?
What if my Inbound Adapter is a `MessageProducerSupport` how to mock this out?

Or should I add a channel after the TCP Server and test my logic by writing into this channel bypassing the TCP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MockIntegrationContext` doesn't currently support replacing inbound endpoints that are not polled `MessageSource` because, yes, we can simply send to the first channel.

You don't need to add a channel to do that, simply get the input channel from the flow...

```
@Autowired
IntegrationFlow itf;

...

    itf.getInputChannel().send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
```

You could also autowire the channel itself, `@Qualified` by its bean name

```
"itf.channel#0"
```